# page not found without forward slash in a url django

Tags: django, http-status-code-404, urlconf

I have the following structure for urls in my `urlconf`

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings


urlpatterns = patterns('app.views',
                     url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='apps/index.html'),
                           name='index'),
                     url(r'^product/list/$','list_of_products' ,name='list_p'),
                     url(r'^product/(?P<product_id>\d+)/$','product_detail' ,name='list_detail'),
                     url(r'^order/(?P<order_id>\d+)/$','order_detail' ,name='order_detail'),
                     url(r'^order/list/$','list_of_orders' ,name='list_orders'),

)
```

So when i tried the above urls in the browsers like below

```
localhost:8000/product/list/
localhost:8000/product/4/
```

yup its working fine, but when i tried the above urls `without forward slash` at the end like below

```
localhost:8000/product/list
localhost:8000/product/4
```

I am getting page not found like below

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/product/list
Using the URLconf defined in urlconf, Django tried these URL patterns, in this 
.......
........
```

So actually why its happening, in the general scenario, even though we had not given the forward slash it should redirect to the required url right?

So can any one let me know how to avoid this, and am i doing anything wrong in defining urlconf ?

Comment: Maybe you have set APPEND_SLASH to False in your settings?

Comment: yeah, din't identified that..... cool and thanks

Comment: You're welcome. I'll post the answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must ensure that `APPEND_SLASH` setting is set to True in your settings.py.
Docs: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash)

Comment: I also have same problem and  I did put that "APPEND_SLASH  = True " in my settings.py file.  But still it does not work. pls help.